# using jq how can i change the value of a key?

Tags: json, jq

Using jq how can i change the value of a key?
I am trying to change the value of a key based on the length of the key. But it seems to not work as expected.

```
echo '[{"kiwi": 3 }, {"apple" : 4} ]' | jq 'map(with_entries(.key |= "\(.)", .value |= (. | length)))'
```

actual output:

```
[
  {
    "kiwi": 3
  },
  {
    "apple": 4
  }
]
```

desired output -

```
[
  {
    "kiwi": 4
  },
  {
    "apple": 5
  }
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want

```
map( with_entries( .value = ( .key | length ) ) )
```

Explanation follows.

---

```
.value |= ( . | length )
```

is roughly equivalent to

```
.value = ( .value | . | length )
```

So you are effectively doing `3 | length` and `4 | length`. When given a number, `length` produces the number. So these produce `3` and `4` respectively.

You want the length of the *key*.

```
.value = ( .key | length )
```

---

Similarly,

```
.key |= "\(.)"
```

can be seen as

```
.key = ( .key | "\(.)" )
```

Since the key is already a string, that's just

```
.key = .key
```

And this does nothing at all.

Answer (score 4):

Within `with_entries`, you only need to assign the computed value (`.key | length`) to `.value` using `=`. The value of `.key` remains unaltered.

```bash
map(with_entries(.value = (.key | length)))
```

```json
[
  {
    "kiwi": 4
  },
  {
    "apple": 5
  }
]
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/q_t1-ReVseo)